# Extended ordering with \cite

Tags: citing

I’m using the `\cite` package with by appearance ordering in the references section. All good, however I’d like to extend the ordering.

Let’s say I use `\cite(zhang2001, fisher2012, primroseIET2013)` yielding (28,1,51).

I could reorder the cites myself, but this is likely to mess up similar ordering elsewhere in the document and would take ages.

What I’m looking for is ordering within the group, if `\cite(fisher2012)` is indeed the first cite it needs to stay as reference 1, but within the final compiled group I’d like (1,28,51).

I've looked at the `cite` package doc to no avail. If this sub sorting was on a group basis only, similar to the options for (1-4) if multiple consecutive citations (1,2,3,4), then it shouldn't mess up the document wide order by appearance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. And a tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if the package "natbib" can do what you want. See here: http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php - It seems as if using the "sort" option in combination to numerical mode should give the style of citations that you want. You might need to change all of your "\cite" commands to "\citep", however.