# Getting the order right when citing literature

Tags: citing

For citation, I use a .bib file and the following commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

The resulting list of literature is in alphabetical order and looks like [image]

But when I cite multiple books like `\cite{somebook}, \cite{anotherbook}, \cite{thirdbook}`, then I often end up with something like
[image]. It would be nicer if the the result was in the correct order `[3], [4], [6]` instead of `[4], [6], [3]`. Of course this depends on the order I am citing the literature in the .tex file, but is there a way to get the correct order automatically without trial and error or checking the alphabetical order of the authors manually?

Minimal working example:

MWE.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
Literature: \cite{Measure2}, \cite{Measure1} \cite{ProbabilityMeasure}
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{MWE}
\end{document}
```

MWE.bib:

```
@Book{ Measure1,
    author = {Vladimir I. Bogachev},
    title = {Measure Theory},
    publisher = {Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
    year = 2007,
}
@Book{ Measure2,
    author = {Donald L. Cohn},
    title = {Measure Theory},
    publisher = {Springer New York},
    year = 2013,
    edition={Second},
    series={Birkh\"auser Advanced Texts Basler Lehrb\"ucher},
}
@Book{ ProbabilityMeasure,
    author = {Patrick Billingsley},
    title = {Probability and Measure},
    publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
    year = 1995,
        edition={Third},
        series={Wiley Series in Probability and Mathematical Statistics},
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a MWE?

Comment: use `\cite{somebook,anotherbook,thirdbook}` so tex sees them together and a package that does ordering and compression of the lists. ` cite` package was I think the first but now several packages do that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, this solves my problem! Do you want to write this as an answer?

Comment: It ought to be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107262/extended-ordering-with-cite?rq=1 but answers there only cover natbib, I'll post something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\cite{somebook,anotherbook,thirdbook}` so tex sees them together and a package that does ordering and compression of the lists. `cite` package was I think the first but now several packages do that, in particular `natbib` has several options to control this behaviour. See also [Extended ordering with \cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107262/extended-ordering-with-cite?rq=1)